# How to remove MediaWiki Help Link from page

Tags: mediawiki

[image: Help icon in corner of special page]

Please, how can I remove this link from my MediaWiki Special Page?

Comment: Do you mean remove from a Special page in an extension you're writing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `SpecialPage::addHelpLink()` in your special page class. You could either add a different help link, or just not add one at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

```
languages/i18n/en.json
```

Line [ 233 ]

Answer (score -1):

I found it:

```
public function addHelpLink( $to, $overrideBaseUrl = false ) {
    global $wgContLang;
    $msg = $this->msg( $wgContLang->lc( $this->getName() ) . '' );//-helppage

    if ( !$msg->isDisabled() ) {
        $helpUrl = Skin::makeUrl( $msg->plain() );
        $this->getOutput()->addHelpLink( $helpUrl, true );
    } else {
        $this->getOutput()->addHelpLink( $to, $overrideBaseUrl );
    }
}
```

I'd just removed -helppage from SpecialPage Class.